# Create ExternalResource from OutputStream in vaadin

Tags: upload, vaadin, cropfield

Is it possible to create an ExternalResource object from the OutputStream object in vaadin? What I want is to allow the user to crop the image uploaded through the Upload component but not save it on the server side. Only when (s)he confirms the cropped area, I'll save it.

The problem is that receiveUpload method of Upload returns OutputStream and I have no idea how to get ExternalResource object from it to pass it to the CropField(addon) constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question: it is possible to create an instance of StreamResource which is perfectly suitable for CropField constructor.

```
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamResource.StreamSource() {

            @Override
            public InputStream getStream() {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            }
        };
        final StreamResource streamRes = new StreamResource(streamSource, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), getApplication());
```